# Where can I get the slider in http://www.ibm.com/us/en/?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Where can i get the script for the slider used in http://www.ibm.com/us/en/? Please notice how  it reacts when mouse is placed on the three inset images of the large images of the slider?

Comment: The thing it does with the three images may well be a custom development.

Comment: I agree with Pekka, that is a custom development, usind the dojo framework. You can figure out yourself if you use Firefox and the plugin Firebug

Comment: when mouse is placed a small capture of the large image is shown. what is it called - popout?

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery and animate. jQuery UI also has some cool effects. Check the demo at http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/

Comment: when mouse is placed a small capture of the large image is shown. what is it called - popout?

Comment: The small image is called a thumbnail.